# Laravel, Products with Attributes in a many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I'm building a platform where Suppliers can add products, and shop owners can 'copy' those products to their shops and sell them.

A Supplier can create products, and he can add all sorts of attributes to them, like the size, colors.

When a Shop wants to use one of the Supplier's products, he can choose which attributes he wants to offer. For example if the Supplier has a T-Shirt in offer with 3 sizes. The shop may choose to sell that T-Shirt with only 2 sizes.

So I have a **Products** table which looks like this. The Supplier adds products in here.

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | description | price |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | T-Shirt     |    10 |
|  2 | Car         |   100 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

I have a Product attributes table, Which is also filled by the Supplier

```
+------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| product_id | description |           options            |
+------------+-------------+------------------------------+
|          1 | size        | ["small", "medium", "large"] |
|          1 | color       | ["white", "black"]           |
+------------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

### Shop Side

When a Shop owner wants a Product. I make a record in the shop_products table, referencing which Shop wants what Product, and adding an optional image, as following

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| shop_id | product_id |   image   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 |          2 | image.jpg |
|       1 |          3 | image.jpg |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

> Now the only issue remaining is: How do I make sure the Shop can choose which attributes he wants to take.

- Should I create a shop_product_attributes table.. But I can't put a relation on the many-to-many because it doesn't have an id?

Comment: Are you wanting it so a shop can limit what products with a particulate attribute they take? so say a t-shirt small black ?

Comment: Yes! A shop can indeed choose which attributes it wants to copy over. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If its possible to change your database structure i would do it this way, i know its a bit of a change to what you have but i think you have to think of a product as a relation, this is because though a t-shirt is a product the actual t-shirt black medium is a completely different product to a t-shirt black small and your suppliers will almost certainly referecne them this way

Your products table would look like this but its not your primary table referencing products, this holds the generic stuff that a product will have such as a description
or a name

```
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------+
| id | name        | price | image     | description |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | Super-T     |    10 | image.jpg | some text   |
|  2 | Focus       |   100 | image.jpg | some text   |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

Your primary table would be a sku table think of this as your product, if you have any sku specific stuff you would put them here

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+
| id | sku         | product_id |  category    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | p1-cb-m     |    1       | t-shirt      |
|  2 | p2-cb-s     |    2       | t shirt      |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

Then have a attributes_sku table, this will link the sku to the attribute

```
+---------------+--------------+
| sku_id        | attribute_id |
+---------------+--------------+
| 1             |    1         |
| 1             |    2         |
+---------------+--------------+
```

Attributes for normalisation

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | type        | name       |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 | color       |    black   |
|  1 | size        |    medium  |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

Shop Sku table

```
+---------+------------+
| shop_id | sku_id     | 
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          1 |
|       1 |          2 |
+---------+------------+
```

the advantages of this is you can do 
`foreach $shop->skus where category = t-shirt` to display all their t-shirts

then you can do $skus->product->name
`$skus->product->attribute->name` or better yet set a relationship on the sku model to be say colour `$this->attribute->where('type', color)`;

Note
A small note i'd further normalise this by having a categories and types table, so your attributes type would actually be a type_id that is a belongs relationship to a types table, and your sku category would be a category_id, to a categories table, this is so in the future if you category or type decides to change name you dont have to edit 1000s of records etc

Comment: This is very wel thought of! It looks like a way better model. how do you come up with a model that good? I always seem to get lost in my tables. I'm going to implement this model (after I fully understand it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That's a really good idea. Is there a method for people with small db knowledge to get from my db 'design' to your version? Or is it just experience that made you come up with this perfect design?

Comment: Its just experience and understanding normalisation, the key is to break things down into chunks and see where you are repeating your self, then normalise them.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, there is one more issue. So now I'm correctly using the SKU as the item a shop owns.. But a Supplier, so the one who creates Products should also be able to choose possible attributes to those products. Should I add a product_attributes listing then? that does the same as the sku_attributes, but for the supplier then?

Comment: Or should I use polymorphism and change sku_attributes to productable_attributes so both the Supplier and the Shop can use the same table to store attributes on?

Comment: if i understand you suppliers creating the products? and the shops are selecting which ones to stock? if so the suppliers will be creating the sku's as well, you shouldn't need any more tables. when they create the product have them assign the skus to the product, and they add the attributes to the sku there.

Comment: No sorry, The suppliers can for example select colors: black, white, gold but the Shop can choose to only show the black and white. So they have different selections of attributes (thanks so much for your time!)

Comment: Okay im a little bit confused now lol, who creates the products?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145654/discussion-between-rchatburn-and-notflip).

Comment: do you have any more time for a chat?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create a many-to-many relation in **shop_product_attributes** table.

Since your **Product Attributes** table has a [compound key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) of 2 fields: `[product_id,description]`, your many-to-many relation will have a trinary-key - `[shop_id,product_id,description]` where `[product_id,description]` is used as a reference foreign-key as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I find it very hard to understand sorry! Should I end up with 2 many-to-many tables then?

Comment: Yes, one for **shop_product** and another one for **shop_product_attributes**.  Even though the 1st one seems a bit useless, it is the correct normalized form.